# aws-cdk to create cloudwatch dashboard using existing Load balancer & ECS service

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am using aws-cdk to create Cloudwatch metric, widget ,dashboard but not sure how to refer existing resources like Load balancer, ECS Service to create these cloudwatch resources.
Here is a POC:

```
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_elasticloadbalancingv2 as elbv2,
    aws_cloudwatch as cw
)
from constructs import Construct

class CwDashboardStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        cpu_utilization_metric = cw.Metric(namespace="AWS/ECS",metric_name="CPUUtilization")
        cpu_widget = cw.GraphWidget(
            title="CPU Utilization",
            height=8,
            width=12,
            left=[cpu_utilization_metric]
        )            

        cw.Dashboard(
            self,
            "Dashboard",
            dashboard_name="Service-Status",
            widgets=[
                [cpu_widget]
            ]
        )
```

But it results in an empty Cloudwatch dashboard:- [image]This is expected as there is no ECS service name, Cluster etc specified.But I can't find corresponding attribute in Metric class where I can put these values.Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't used CDK, but I'm familiar with CW Dashboards/Metrics. Wouldn't the service name and cluster be part of the dimensions_map attribute of the `cw.Metric()` call? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_cloudwatch/Metric.html

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceName and ClusterName can be passed along as part of the `dimenion_maps` parameter of the `cw.Metric()` call.

Doing a bit of experimenting locally with CDK, I didn't have an ECS cluster handy to work with, but here's an example of providing a dimension_maps parameter to the `cw.Metric()` call:

```python
        r53_utilization_metric = cw.Metric(
            namespace="AWS/Route53",
            metric_name="DNSQueries",
            dimensions_map = {
                "HostedZoneId": "<...>"
            }
        )
        r53_widget = cw.GraphWidget(
            title="Route53 Utilization",
            height=8,
            width=12,
            left=[r53_utilization_metric]
        )
        cw.Dashboard(
            self,
            "Dashboard",
            dashboard_name="Service-Status",
            widgets=[
                [r53_widget]
            ]
        )
```

Hopefully that gives you an idea on how to proceed.